# How to reason that $||x||=||x+0||$

Tags: normed-spaces

> How to reason that $||x||=||x+0||$ for all $x$ in the real numbers where $||\cdot||$ denotes the Norm and $0$ the neutral element and $x$ is a real number.

It is obvious but I want to be very formal. We have that $0+x=x$ virtually by definition. The norm is a function and since every function is well-definied meaning that if $x_1=x_2$ it follows that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ we find that $x=x+0$ implies $||x||=||x+0||$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I would remove the reference to the fact that functions are well-defined.

Comment: @littleO Well technically by homogeneity $||x||=|x|\cdot||1||=\alpha|x|$ are other valid norms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ is a function, $x$ and $y$ are in the domain of $f$, and $x=y$, then $f(x)=f(y)$. This is known as the [substitution property of equality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equality_(mathematics)#Basic_properties).

So the fact that $|x|=|x+0|$ follows not just from the fact that $|\cdot |$ is a function, but from the properties of equality.

Answer (score 1):

We can also just use properties of norms to show this. We know $\Vert 0 \Vert = 0$ and we have the triangle inequalities,
$$
\Vert x \Vert - \Vert y \Vert \leq \Vert x+y \Vert \leq \Vert x \Vert + \Vert y \Vert
$$
so using these two properties with $y=0$ yields,
$$
\Vert x \Vert = \Vert x\Vert - \Vert 0 \Vert \leq \Vert x + 0 \Vert
$$
and also
$$
\Vert x+0\Vert \leq \Vert x\Vert + \Vert 0 \Vert = \Vert x\Vert
$$
showing that $\Vert x \Vert = \Vert x+0\Vert$.